# Limit IIS Log Size

Tags: windows-server-2008, logging, iis, administration

Is there a setting in IIS that lets you limit the size of each log file? I know you can do compression, move to a different drive, etc. but not interested in those.

As an alternative, is there a way to filter what sort of events get logged in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a setting to limit the size of the file, only the duration. You could set the time down to hourly then use another process to remove all files older than a certain date or similar. There's a technique for this practice explained on:
http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/managing-iis-log-file-storage

Essentially you'd use a script to trim out the folder contents. That script runs automatically on a schedule, via a scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Server 2008 anymore but in Server 2008 R2 and newer you can.

In IIS Manager, select your site and open the `Logging` feature and select `Maximum file size` and specify a number of bytes. If the log file reaches this limit, a new file is created.

You can also remove some field to make the log file smaller.

[image]

To do the same in PowerShell:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site']/logFile" -name "truncateSize" -value 5242880
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site']/logFile" -name "period" -value MaxSize
```

Comment: This works in Server 2008 (non R2) as well! Thank you so much!